# DirectX: The best way to get RGB data from ID3D11Texture2D with DXGI_FORMAT_NV12 format?

Tags: rgb, directx-11, yuv, texture2d

I'm using DirectX to draw videos. After decoding by Intel Media SDK. And then I draw it by the following Intel's Code:

```
mfxStatus CD3D11Device::RenderFrame(mfxFrameSurface1 * pSrf, mfxFrameAllocator * pAlloc)
{
    HRESULT hres = S_OK;
    mfxStatus sts;

    sts = CreateVideoProcessor(pSrf);
    MSDK_CHECK_STATUS(sts, "CreateVideoProcessor failed");

    hres = m_pSwapChain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof( ID3D11Texture2D ), (void**)&m_pDXGIBackBuffer.p);
    if (FAILED(hres))
        return MFX_ERR_DEVICE_FAILED;

    D3D11_VIDEO_PROCESSOR_OUTPUT_VIEW_DESC OutputViewDesc;
    if (2 == m_nViews)
    {
        m_pVideoContext->VideoProcessorSetStreamStereoFormat(m_pVideoProcessor, 0, TRUE,D3D11_VIDEO_PROCESSOR_STEREO_FORMAT_SEPARATE,
            TRUE, TRUE, D3D11_VIDEO_PROCESSOR_STEREO_FLIP_NONE, NULL);
        m_pVideoContext->VideoProcessorSetOutputStereoMode(m_pVideoProcessor,TRUE);

        OutputViewDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_VPOV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2DARRAY;
        OutputViewDesc.Texture2DArray.ArraySize = 2;
        OutputViewDesc.Texture2DArray.MipSlice = 0;
        OutputViewDesc.Texture2DArray.FirstArraySlice = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        OutputViewDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_VPOV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
        OutputViewDesc.Texture2D.MipSlice = 0;
    }

    if (1 == m_nViews || 0 == pSrf->Info.FrameId.ViewId)
    {
        hres = m_pDX11VideoDevice->CreateVideoProcessorOutputView(
            m_pDXGIBackBuffer,
            m_VideoProcessorEnum,
            &OutputViewDesc,
            &m_pOutputView.p );
        if (FAILED(hres))
            return MFX_ERR_DEVICE_FAILED;
    }

    D3D11_VIDEO_PROCESSOR_INPUT_VIEW_DESC InputViewDesc;
    InputViewDesc.FourCC = 0;
    InputViewDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_VPIV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
    InputViewDesc.Texture2D.MipSlice = 0;
    InputViewDesc.Texture2D.ArraySlice = 0;

    mfxHDLPair pair = {NULL};
    sts = pAlloc->GetHDL(pAlloc->pthis, pSrf->Data.MemId, (mfxHDL*)&pair);
    MSDK_CHECK_STATUS(sts, "pAlloc->GetHDL failed");

    ID3D11Texture2D  *pRTTexture2D = reinterpret_cast<ID3D11Texture2D*>(pair.first);
    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC RTTexture2DDesc;

    if(!m_pTempTexture && m_nViews == 2)
    {
        pRTTexture2D->GetDesc(&RTTexture2DDesc);
        hres = m_pD3D11Device->CreateTexture2D(&RTTexture2DDesc,NULL,&m_pTempTexture.p);
        if (FAILED(hres))
            return MFX_ERR_DEVICE_FAILED;
    }

    // Creating input views for left and righ eyes
    if (1 == m_nViews)
    {
        hres = m_pDX11VideoDevice->CreateVideoProcessorInputView(
            pRTTexture2D,
            m_VideoProcessorEnum,
            &InputViewDesc,
            &m_pInputViewLeft.p );

    }
    else if (2 == m_nViews && 0 == pSrf->Info.FrameId.ViewId)
    {
        m_pD3D11Ctx->CopyResource(m_pTempTexture,pRTTexture2D);
        hres = m_pDX11VideoDevice->CreateVideoProcessorInputView(
            m_pTempTexture,
            m_VideoProcessorEnum,
            &InputViewDesc,
            &m_pInputViewLeft.p );
    }
    else
    {
        hres = m_pDX11VideoDevice->CreateVideoProcessorInputView(
            pRTTexture2D,
            m_VideoProcessorEnum,
            &InputViewDesc,
            &m_pInputViewRight.p );
    }
    if (FAILED(hres))
        return MFX_ERR_DEVICE_FAILED;

    //  NV12 surface to RGB backbuffer
    RECT rect = {0};
    rect.right  = pSrf->Info.CropW;
    rect.bottom = pSrf->Info.CropH;

    D3D11_VIDEO_PROCESSOR_STREAM StreamData;

    if (1 == m_nViews || pSrf->Info.FrameId.ViewId == 1)
    {
        StreamData.Enable = TRUE;
        StreamData.OutputIndex = 0;
        StreamData.InputFrameOrField = 0;
        StreamData.PastFrames = 0;
        StreamData.FutureFrames = 0;
        StreamData.ppPastSurfaces = NULL;
        StreamData.ppFutureSurfaces = NULL;
        StreamData.pInputSurface = m_pInputViewLeft;
        StreamData.ppPastSurfacesRight = NULL;
        StreamData.ppFutureSurfacesRight = NULL;
        StreamData.pInputSurfaceRight = m_nViews == 2 ? m_pInputViewRight : NULL;

        m_pVideoContext->VideoProcessorSetStreamSourceRect(m_pVideoProcessor, 0, true, &rect);
        m_pVideoContext->VideoProcessorSetStreamFrameFormat( m_pVideoProcessor, 0, D3D11_VIDEO_FRAME_FORMAT_PROGRESSIVE);
        hres = m_pVideoContext->VideoProcessorBlt( m_pVideoProcessor, m_pOutputView, 0, 1, &StreamData );
        if (FAILED(hres))
            return MFX_ERR_DEVICE_FAILED;
    }

    if (1 == m_nViews || 1 == pSrf->Info.FrameId.ViewId)
    {
        DXGI_PRESENT_PARAMETERS parameters = {0};
        hres = m_pSwapChain->Present1(0, 0, &parameters);
        if (FAILED(hres))
            return MFX_ERR_DEVICE_FAILED;
    }

    return MFX_ERR_NONE;
}
```

From the code's line:

```
ID3D11Texture2D  *pRTTexture2D = reinterpret_cast<ID3D11Texture2D*>(pair.first);
```

I had `pRTTexture2D` is a `ID3D11Texture2D` with DXGI_FORMAT_NV12 format.

I want to get RGB data from this texture, and I tried to using the below way:

1) Map the texture use `d3dContext->Map(Texture, 0, D3D11_MAP_READ, 0, &mapInfo) => must copy to the staging resource in my case`

2) Create a `RGB Array` on System Memory and calculate to convert from NV12 on `mapInfo` to `RGB Array`.

This way worked ok, but I want to do it with the better way. Because I guess that while rendering `(RenderFrame() Function)` the DirectX converted Texture in to RGB in BackBuffer, and if I can get data form that BackBuffer, that will be great.

Someone can show me the code to do above way. Or is there any better way to implement it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you solve it? Can you share a bit source? Tks

Answer (score 0):

D3DXSaveSurfaceToFileInMemory, use this API, Maybe it can bring you some ideas.